# Laravel - search form with filters and old input

Tags: javascript, php, eloquent

I'm developing a search form with filters, e.g. choose a gender from this list, choose an area etc., where these filters should be applied dynamically to the search query. The form submits with a post request in a controller. My question is now: How do I return the query result from the db to the search page, keeping the same, pretty url, and in addition return the old input for prepopulating the form with old data?

Regards.

EDIT:

I have tried something like this:

```
public function advancedSearch()
{
    $users = Session::get('users');

    return View("find-match.show", compact("users"));
}



public function getUsersAdvancedSearch(Request $request)
{
    $users = User::select();

    //Only active users excluding own profile.
    $users->where('is_activated', 1)
          ->where('id', '<>', Auth::user()->id);

    //Add gender.
    if($request->has('form_genders'))
    {
        $users->whereIn('gender_id', $request->form_genders);
    }

    //Get matching users.   
    $users = $users->Paginate(self::paginate);


    Session::put('users', $users);


    return redirect()->route('match.advancedSearch')->withInput();
}
```

Comment: Choosing gender from a list in 2018. LUL good luck with that

Comment: Why not? I want users to be able to search for men or women only.

Comment: What have you currently tried? Can you post some sample code?

Comment: I have updated my question with sample code.

Comment: Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Do not edit the word "Solved" into the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a Resource Controller and the "old" function of laravel to keep old post data for re population, and use the same url

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#resource-controllers

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#old-input